# Forward incoming request from specific ip to a local ip and port in ubuntu

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-18.04

I have assigned a local Ip 192.168.1.253 to an instance(Openstack instance) running on my machine. The Ip address of my physical machine on the local network is 10.59.1.150, I can access 10.59.1.150 from my internal network. I want to redirect the incoming requests of 10.59.1.150:4000 to 192.168.1.253:4000.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved using:
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
Link: http://jensd.be/343/linux/forward-a-tcp-port-to-another-ip-or-port-using-nat-with-iptables